# Why when I create a element in jQuery do event handlers/listeners not work for them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am currently just creating a simple to-do-list to work on jquery skills and I am confused as to why when I create an element/tag in jquery the event handlers do to activate for these elements, but do for elements I have created in my html file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have only been able to get these newly created elements to activate the event listeners by putting separate event listeners in the "click" event I use to create the new elements.

This is my current jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    let row = $('.row');

    let text = $("textarea");

    text.on('input', function(element){
        expandTextArea(element.currentTarget);
    });

    let trash = $('.fa-trash');

    trash.on("click",  function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    })


    let end = $('.end');
    let add = $(".fa-plus");

    add.on("click", function(){

        let newrow = $('<div></div>')
            .addClass('row');

        let newcheckBox = $('<input>')
            .attr('type', 'checkbox')
            .addClass('checkbox')
            .appendTo(newrow);

        let newtext = $('<textarea></textarea>')
            .attr('placeholder', 'Example task.....')
            .attr('rows', '1')
            .appendTo(newrow);

        let newtrash = $('<i></i>')
            .addClass('fa-sharp fa-solid fa-trash')
            .appendTo(newrow);

        end.before(newrow);

        text = $('textarea')
        text.on('input', function(element){
            expandTextArea(element.currentTarget);
        });

        trash = $('.fa-trash');

        trash.on("click",  function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        })
    });
});


function expandTextArea(element){
    element.style.height = "";
    element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.fa-trash').on('click', someFn)` will loop over all elements matched by the selector `.fa-trash` at the current time and attach a click event listener to each of them. It does not attempt to handle new elements added to the page later on that match the selector.

You could instead use the three argument form of `.on` for event delegation. For the above example, it could look like:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.fa-trash', someFn);
```

This method will handle elements that are dynamically added to the page since it essentially listens for click events that bubble to the `document` and checks if the `target` matches the selector passed as the second argument. Of course, it is better to attach the listener to nearest static ancestor (if one can be found apart from `document`) of all the `.fa-trash` elements.

Comment: Thanks, this worked and made a lot of sense!